# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, logging, noclassdeffounderror

I have actually figured this problem out, but it took me days, so I thought I would paste my solution here to aide others.

I am using Fedora 11, and in Eclipse I tried adding a Tomcat 6 server and starting it. I would get the following error:

> 'Starting Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.
>
> Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

Then in my console I got the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:336)
  ... 1 more
Could not find the main class: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap. Program will exit.
```

I'll post the solution in an answer below.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://forums.opensuse.org/applications/391114-tomcat6-eclipse-not-working.html

> 1. In Eclipse, Open the "Server" tab.
> 2. Double click on the "Tomcat6" entry to see the configuration.
> 3. Then click on the "Open launch configuration" link in the "General information" block.
> 4. In the dialog, select the "Classpath" tab.
> 5. Click the "Add external jar" button.
> 6. Select the file "/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/tomcat-juli.jar"
> 7. Close the dialog.
> 8. Start tomcat 6 from Eclipse.

Hopefully posting it here will help some poor soul.

Comment: Thanks man, i had this problem too and your solution just worked instantly!

Comment: What if you are seeing this problem and not using Eclipse at all?

Comment: @rob what u needed is to add external jars to server configuration (apache tomcat) on your IDE.

Comment: I don't have tomcat6 inside /usr/share/.

Comment: It did not work for me, my tomcat-juli.jar file is in a different folder though.

Comment: I had to change the permission as well. I chowned it to the user.

Answer (score 8):

I copied the contents of the "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\conf" directory to the "workspace\Servers\Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost-config" directory for Eclipse.  I refreshed the "Servers\Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost-config" folder in the Eclipse Project Explorer and then everything was good.

Comment: This is what worked for me - I also had to restart Eclipse though.

Comment: i tried `switch location button to \Servers\Tomcat v6.0 ` it was workspace metadata

Answer (score 2):

1. install tomcat

   # yum install tomcat6*
2. edit tomcat conf file

   # vim /etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml

something like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
  <user username="TomcatAdmin" password="tomcat" roles="admin,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

1. create root directory for your J2EE project, example:

   $ mkdir -p ~/Project/java/
2. do symbolic link,  /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/  to ~/Project/java/

   # ln -s /home//Project/java//dist/.war /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/.war

Note: war archive file is created automatcaly when you use netbeans

0r you can do:

```
# ln -s /home/<login>/Project/java/<myProject>/webapps /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/<myProject>
```

1. check  /etc/hosts file, this file must contain the machine name, mine hosts file

   jonathan 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
   ::1      localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
2. start httpd service

   # service httpd start
3. check loclahost web page
4. start tomcat6

   # service tomcat6 start
5. check localhost:8080 web page
6. check that tomcat show your project
   if not:

   - check symbolic link and restart tomcat6 service
   - or add manualy with tomcat manager web page
     a) Set project name
     b) Se path to web.xml file
     c) Valid
     d) start your project (from web page)

for fedora 13 and under they are some problem, how fix it:

```
# chmod -R g+w /var/log/tomcat6 /etc/tomcat6/Catalina  
# chmod -R g+w /usr/share/tomcat6/work/
```

check in log files located in /var/log/tomcat6/ if they are anymore "permission denied" message

Answer (score 2):

aforementioned solutions did not help me, I could solve it by re-installing the Tomcat server which took few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

On my PC I had to open the Tomcat6 entry again after the 7th step mentioned above and then change the default option under `Server locations` to `Use tomcat installation`.