# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Seem to have a problem starting my Java app:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.(LifecycleBase.java:37)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)     ... 1 more

Tried the solution here:
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392383/server-tomcat-v6-0-server-at-localhost-failed-to-start)

But I see tomcat-juli.jar already. Also I'm using Tomcat 7. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your vm does not find the class `org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory` check if this class is present in the tomcat-juli.jar that you use (unzip it and search the file), if it's not present download the library from apache web site else if it's present put the tomcat-juli.jar in a path (the lib directory) that Tomcat use to load classes. If your Tomcat does not find it you can copy the jar in the lib directory of the JRE that you are using.

Comment: Works very well ... :D
[Maven-Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-juli) 
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
    <version>${used.tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: jfyi, `tomcat-juli.jar` is provided in the `bin/` directory when downloading tomcat zip and NOT in the `lib` directory.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into this problem when using `tomcat-embed-core::7.0.47`, from Maven.  I'm not sure why they didn't add `tomcat-util` as a runtime dependency, so I added my own runtime dependency to my own project.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
  <version><!-- version from tomcat-embed-core --></version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Helped a lot, using Spring Boot with a Servlet 3.0 compatible version of Tomcat. I had to add this, thanks! (Mine is at scope "provided" currently though).

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me because I was using a Tomcat 5.5 `catalina.sh` file with a Tomcat 7 installation.  Using the `catalina.sh` that came with the Tomcat 7 install fixed the problem.

Comment: This is not an answer. This should have been in comments.

Comment: @AdityaSingh  This **is** an answer. it includes diagnosis of the problem and specification of a resolution. It happens to be **succint** - which in no way disqualifies it.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using jsvc to run tomcat as tomcat (run `/etc/init.d/tomcat` as root), edit `/etc/init.d/tomcat` and add `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/tomcat-juli.jar` to `CLASSPATH`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, What helped me was:

1. Right click on the project.
2. Click '**Properties**'
3. Go to '**Java Build Path**'
4. And then: '**Libraries**'
5. In there, Click: **Add External Jars**
6. Add: ''**Path/To/Tomcat/Bin/tomcat-juli.jar**

Done .

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the wrong version of the Sysdeo Tomcat plugin for Eclipse 3.5 was being used. The fix:

- Use `tomcatPluginV33` instead of `tomcatPluginV321` (extract to `C:\eclipse\dropins`)
- Ensure that `DevloaderTomcat7.jar` was placed in the tomcat `lib` folder
- In Window > Preferences > Tomcat, set the Tomcat version to 7.x

This problem may have been unique to our environment; but, I'll record it here anyway, for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
/usr/share# mv /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/ tomcat7
```

fixed the issue for me. There was a symbolic link there to /opt. Inside that opt directory there where ../../java links that would not point to /usr/share/java since the files physically were in /opt