# tomcat in linux:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat-juli

when I startup tomcat in linux,I met a problem.
    `Using CLASSPATH:/data/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/bootstrap.jar:/data/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/tomcat-juli.jar`

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 1 more`
```

I know that class can't be found,but the jar has been in the classpath. So why? I will be appreciated if you can answer my question.thank you.

Comment: can u share your classpath also?

Comment: when ./catalina.sh run it shows "Using CLASSPATH: /data/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/bootstrap.jar:/data/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/tomcat-juli.jar"

Comment: Seems like LogFactory might require a class from a jar not on your classpath, or is not in the jars you've listed. Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955442/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-juli-logging-logfactory?rq=1

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with `tomcat-juli.jar`. Maybe the file is demaged.

Comment: I experience this problem regularly when I start Tomcat from Eclipse (might not apply in your case). Running "Clean..." from the context menu in the server view fixes it. It seems to be a synchronization problem between the Eclipse workspace and the Tomcat working directory.

Comment: Seems like your tomcat installation is broken

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was in skiped quotes "" after --Classpath.
The correct run script is

```
%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat7 //IS//Tomcat7 --DisplayName="Apache Tomcat 7" --Install="C:\tomcat-7.0\bin\tomcat7.exe" --Jvm=auto --StartMode=jvm --StopMode=jvm --Classpath="%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\bootstrap.jar;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" --StartClass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StartParams=start --StopClass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StopParams=stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I also underwent the same problem while I started the tomcat. But after following changes it started working properly. So you better add the below mentioned jars to your classpath and start the tomcat server again.

- bootstrap.jar
- common-daemon.jar
- tomcat-juli.jar

As you already have 'bootstrap.jar' and 'tomcat-juli.jar', add '**common-daemon.jar**' to the classpath and start the server.

*Cheers !!*

Answer (score -1):

Goto Project->clean and clean your project. will resolve your problem