# Eclipse Tomcat java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError LogFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I've been struggling with this error for the past few days java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory Below is the console output.

I am using the latest versions of Tomcat and Eclipse. EDIT - I tried uninstalling WAMP and installing the latest version of MYSQL community server to no avail; I'm still getting the same error.

Note - I've consulted topics with the same issue yet none of the solutions suggested work for me. For example: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955442/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-juli-logging-logfactory)

I tried adding tomcat-juli.jar as an external jar via the server classpath configuration in Eclipse, updating the system environment variable Classpath, copying the tomcat-juli.jar file into the lib folder of the JRE, and opening the file and confirming that the LogFactory class is indeed present.

EDIT - Also, I am able to run the Tomcat server and view the default page in the browser by running startup.bat Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.30 using APR version 1.4.8.
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:13 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server: ' did not find a matching property.
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014)
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1657 ms
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.9
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [127] milliseconds.
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ ]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:868)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ ]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.<clinit>(BasicDataSource.java:70)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:193)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:182)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:841)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:829)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1084)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:663)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5083)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 22 more

Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:868)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jul 11, 2014 12:38:15 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl cleanUp
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ ]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class loader
    at org.apache.naming.ContextBindings.getClassLoader(ContextBindings.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:975)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5415)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:272)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1013)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1013)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:603)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:842)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: 'file into the lib folder of the JRE...' is incorrect, you have to put it to $TOMCAT_HOME\lib folder. $TOMCAT_HOME is a path of your tomcat installation.

Comment: It's also located in the $TOMCAT_HOME\lib folder

Comment: Are you sure you ahve this  tomcat-juli.jar in the classpath

Comment: Yes, I added it via Tomcat server configuration in Eclipse to Classpath as an external jar and to the classpath under System > Environment Variables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Make sure your tomcat launch configuration has correct juli jar in
  classpath.

[image: Tomcat launch configuration]

- Also where is your DBCP jars located? Try putting juli jar in same
  location

JDK 1.8 that I have has following JARs in "jre\lib\ext". Move all other jars to tomcat endorsed as specified.

```
access-bridge-64.jar
cldrdata.jar
dnsns.jar
jaccess.jar
jfxrt.jar
localedata.jar
meta-index
nashorn.jar
sunec.jar
sunjce_provider.jar
sunmscapi.jar
sunpkcs11.jar
zipfs.jar
```

Comment: I just double checked and the tomcat launch configuration does have the correct tomcat-juli.jar classpath. My tomcat-dbcp.jar file is in the lib folder. I tried moving the tomcat-juli.jar file into the lib folder as well (changed the classpath in server configuration and updated System Environment Variables (shutdown to take effect) and still am getting the same error.

Comment: Try deleting server entry in eclipse and create it again so that new server configuration in eclipse may be able to pickup juli from lib folder

Comment: After using -verbose:class as @Shailendra suggested I discovered that tomcat-dbcp.jar was being loaded from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\ext so I copied tomcat-juli.jar into this folder as well and updated the Server Configuration External Jar entry as well as the System Environment Variables (shutdown to take effect). After doing this it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have tomcat-dbcp.jar in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\ext dir ?

Comment: I don't know. I'm following instructions from someone else on the team passing off the setup and code to me for eventual enterprise deployment. I'm fairly certain there is or was a specific purpose for it though when it was originally set up that way.

Comment: Unless you intend to extend JVM functionality I would not recommend doing this [ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html ].  If needs really be you can use endorsed dir feature as mentioned in this XML Parsers and Java section [ http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#XML_Parsers_and_Java ] and have those libs relocated in $CATALINA_HOME/endorsed dir.

Comment: The application does need to extend JVM functionality

Comment: If it is DBCP, it's tomcat that needs it, not JVM unless you have something else there.

Comment: There are a number of other jars in my C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\ext folder including mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar and commons-codec-1.9.jar

Comment: JDK 1.8 that I have has following JARS in

Answer (score 2):

Here is what should definitely help you to find the cause. Append following to your tomcat jvm startup parameter

```
-verbose:class
```

If you are running standalone Tomcat (by running `startup.bat`) you can put following lines in the `catalina.bat`

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -verbose:class
```

What this does is print on the console / log  - the class  and the jar file location from which it is loaded beginning with the java bootstrap till the server bootstrap and your application classes. In short all the required classes for successfully running your application. The information is verbose but very useful in pinpointing the exact jar from the which the classes are picked or even if the jar is not being picked. It would be very helpful if you output the information to a file and then do a text search with a text editor.

On my Tomcat installation, it shows information like this

```
[Loaded java.lang.Void from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory from file:/D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/tomcat-juli.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.juli.logging.Log from file:/D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/tomcat-juli.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog from file:/D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/tomcat-juli.jar]
[Loaded java.util.logging.Logger from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.logging.Handler from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\rt.jar]
```

You can see the `org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory` being loaded  from `file:/D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/tomcat-juli.jar`

Comment: How do I append that to the tomcat jvm startup parameter?

Comment: I also added "call startup.bat >textfile.txt 2>&1" to catalina.bat
In the output textfile.txt it says:
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.9"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.9"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"

Comment: Go to startup.bat..modify 
call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS% to 
call "%EXECUTABLE%" run %CMD_LINE_ARG...so that the tomcat runs in single command window. Then run tomcat by going to the bin directory of Tomcat installation and typing on command prompt startup.bat > textfile.txt

Comment: Okay, in the textfile it says [Loaded org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory from file:/C:/Program%20Files/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar]
I never had any issues running Tomcat via startup.bat The problem only happens when I try to run Tomcat via Eclipse. Any ideas?

Comment: It means the library is correctly being picked up in standalone tomcat. Now you can repeat the same steps for Tomcat server being run from inside eclipse. Double click on Server -> Tomcat -> Open Launch Configuration ->Argument and add -verbose:class and start the server. You can investigate the eclipse console in similar manner. What I am guessing is that your Open launch Configuration -> Classpath does not contain entry for tomcat-juli.jar

Comment: I double checked and Configuration -> Classpath does have an entry for tomcat-juli.jar I added the Argument -verbose:class and tried running the server again but got the same error as before (original post). The console in Eclipse didn't contain any more details.

Comment: If you added -verbose:class then the eclipse console should be having the classloading details. On my test environment it prints all the information. Does it contains any entry for tomcat-juli jar

Comment: I'm not seeing any entry so I must be doing it incorrectly. Under Server Configuration -> Argument I am adding -verbose:class before start in the Program arguments box. I tried adding set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -verbose:class before start as well but got the same result.

Comment: You have to add that in VM arguments and not Program arguments as these arguments are meant for JVM.

Comment: Okay, I see the details now. I searched for tomcat-juli.jar in the console log but didn't get any results. The phrase "juli" is only shown twice in the console and is contained in the same error messages as in my original post.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out with your and Gladwin's help. See my above comment under Gladwin's answer.

Comment: Great ! Glad that your perseverance paid off !

Answer (score 0):

Although previous answer posted solves issue but it is a dirty solution.

Configure your DBCP jars correctly as specified in following links. Also move out any other jars to $CATALINA_HOME/endorsed dir

[JNDI Datasource HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

[The Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the checklist :-

1. Same copy of tomcat-juli.jar is present at JRE\lib,TOMCAT\lib and launch configuration of eclipse,to make sure one used contains LogFactory.
2. You are using Eclipse's in built in server configuration tool instead of a plugin.
3. Could be a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51249%22bug%22) in tomcat's version you are using.