# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

Trying to start tomcat7 and I get this error:

```
Buildfile: E:\Workspace\test\config\deploy\build.xml
tomcat.start:
     [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
     [java]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:60)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     [java]     ... 1 more
     [java] Could not find the main class: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap. Program will exit.
     [java] Exception in thread "main" 
     [java] Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 923 milliseconds
```

i use this link: [ [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955442/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-juli-logging-logfactory?lq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955442/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-juli-logging-logfactory) ] and copy "tomcat-juli.jar" in my JRE and ... , **but doesn't work**

tnx

p.s: when i change tomcat 6 to 7 i give this error , my project worked before of this change!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955442/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-juli-logging-logfactory?lq=1

Comment: yes i know , i do all the thing in that topic and reference it in my question, it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 8):

This error is occuring due to missing  tomcat-juli.jar in the Launch environment in Eclipse

I solved it by doing the below steps-

1.Double click on the installed Ode v1.x Server in the 'Server' View.

2.Click on Open launch configuration.

3.Choose  Classpath tab >
    Add External JARs > [your TOMCAT_DIR]\bin\tomcat-juli.jar.

4.Click Apply then OK.

5.Start your Tomcat Server

Answer (score 2):

Please check if your tomcat server has `tomcat-juli.jar` in *$TOMCAT_HOME/lib* directory. Looks like it is the problem with tomcat server jar files. Please check your installation for correctness

Note : Please see the error

> Could not find the main class: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap. Program will exit.

It doesn't even get started. It couldn't find the main class itself

Comment: tnx :) , how can i check installation for correctness?

Comment: @SDWACW Check if you have all .jar files in lib directory?

Comment: i checked i have all jar in lib

Comment: ok, Can you redownload from this link - http://mirror.nexcess.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.55/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.55.zip

Comment: no , just error in my question, mean:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory and ...

Comment: Full path on Centos: `/usr/share/tomcat/lib/tomcat-juli.jar`; gets installed by default so if it is missing there is something wrong with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you miss the `tomcat-juli.jar` in your classpath. Download and add it to your classpath.

Comment: tnx :) ,but it was exist in my class path!- bin folder of tomcat-

Comment: I must be in the `lib` folder, not in `bin`.

Comment: @SDWACW have you restarted the tomcat?

Comment: @SDWACW Can you take a look to the jar, and verify that the class is in it? And is the jar added to the classpath at build time?

Answer (score 0):

try referencing the jar by a classpath entry,

currently it is not getting referenced
and make sure you have tomcat correctly installed

Comment: tnx :) , how i can do?

Comment: you are using ant?
I am able to see build.xml in your Question,

anyways add the JAR file in your lib folder instead of bin folder @Jens has pointed it out already

Comment: someone has pointed out its a duplicate question
try making those changes,if it doesnt work your build file might be playing some tricks

Comment: i know and  i do all points, my build file and tomcat works yesterday , but when i change tomcat 6 to 7 , i get this error! tnx

Comment: are you using tomcat 7.0.43 or higher?

Comment: use this link https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55336 it might be the cause of your problem

Comment: i use apache-tomcat-7.0.11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60802/discussion-between-vihar-and-sdwacw).

Comment: I have the exact same issue, have you found a solution ?

Comment: @SDWACW Can you share your solution if you got it working with tomcat 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting Tomcat with a Windows Batchfile. The problem occurred with Tomcat 7 + 8 + 8.5. You have to add bootstrap.jar and tomcat-juli.jar to your classpath.

Solution in my Batchfile:

```
@echo off
SET TOMCAT_OPTS=-cp bootstrap.jar;tomcat-juli.jar
REM Go to your tomcat/bin directory
cd tomcat/bin
catalina.bat start
```