# Starting Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost fails

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6

I am not able to start Tomcat v6.0 from Eclipse Helios.

I have my Java bin path set properly.

Moreover, I can start the server from outside of Eclipse manually. I could start it from Windows Services as well as using tomcat6.exe and see that it works correctly in my browser by typing localhost:8080 in the URL, but when I start from Eclipse a window appears saying that it encountered a problem while starting tomcat.

And my Console shows the following error:-

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1847)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:890)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1354)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1847)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:890)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1354)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1094)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4058)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4371)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
... 6 more
```

I also tried a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392383/server-tomcat-v6-0-server-at-localhost-failed-to-start), but the problem still persists. However, the problem there is different from what I get.

How do I solve this?

Comment: when you are trying to start from the eclipse are you trying to run some project? `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener` seems you are trying something with spring and might be you have not included the required jars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you're building some web-app with spring support.

You have to export dependencies into tomcat.

project_properties -> Java build path -> Order and Export tab.

On this tab check all checkboxes which are relevant (you have to check spring at least).
Push OK.
Redeploy