# Getting exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while running application on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7

I am trying to launch spring application on tomcat,
Getting below exception while launching it on tomcat V7.0:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:804)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.SetNextNamingRule.end(SetNextNamingRule.java:104)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1057)
...............
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:637)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:574)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:842)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:335)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
.......
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Hashtable.put(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.addResource(NamingResources.java:353)
... 45 more
Sep 16, 2014 3:21:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processContextConfig
SEVERE: Parse error in context.xml
```

I have added JDBC resources in context.xml, thereafter i am getting this exception.

Comment: I think you need to call them out in web.xml as well.  See Tomcat JNDI docs.

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601364/starting-tomcat-v6-0-server-at-localhost-fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with Tomcat version installed through eclipse.
Downloaded other tomcat version from apache site, now it's working ok.