# tomcat server not starting in Linux

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat5.5

I have installed tomcat version 5.5.17 in my linux system.

When i tried to start tomcat, i got below exception.

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./catalina.sh run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:       /usr/lib/jvm/java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: while resolving class: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.resolveClass(java.lang.Class) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass() (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at gnu.gcj.runtime.FirstThread.run() (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at _Jv_ThreadRun(java.lang.Thread) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at _Jv_RunMain(java.lang.Class, byte const, int, byte const, boolean) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at __gcj_personality_v0 (/usr/local/tomcat/bin/java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre)
   at __libc_start_main (/lib/tls/libc-2.3.3.so)
   at _Jv_RegisterClasses (/usr/local/tomcat/bin/java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.management.ObjectName not found in [file:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar, file:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/commons-logging-api.jar, file:/usr/share/java/libgcj-3.4.2.jar, file:./, core:/]
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at gnu.gcj.runtime.VMClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at _Jv_FindClass(_Jv_Utf8Const, java.lang.ClassLoader) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at _Jv_BytecodeVerifier.verify_instructions_0() (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at _Jv_VerifyMethod(_Jv_InterpMethod) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at _Jv_PrepareClass(java.lang.Class) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at _Jv_WaitForState(java.lang.Class, int) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.linkClass0(java.lang.Class) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.resolveClass(java.lang.Class) (/usr/lib/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   ...9 more
[root@localhost bin]#
```

could anyone help me in proceeding with this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392383/server-tomcat-v6-0-server-at-localhost-failed-to-start