# Soleustions for Tomcat with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, server

I get this problem running Apache server on eclipse

Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at \Servers\Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config/web.xml'.

I need your help please

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the Servers folder in eclipse?

Comment: Look at the steps into my answer bellow.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that tomcat files have changed and your eclipse still have the old tomcat files... this might happen if you manually deploy something on your tomcat or for some other reasons.

1. I would try to refresh the Servers folder in eclipse (right click > refresh or just F5) and see if the problem disappears

[image]

2. If this does not work. I would delete the tomcat servers in eclipse and recreate it  (right click in the server view and click "new Server")

[image]

Comment: I spent so long on this issue. A damn refresh fixed it. Thanks :x

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to follow:

1. In Eclipse, Open the "Server" tab.
2. Double click on the "Tomcat7" entry to see the configuration.
3. Then click on the "Open launch configuration" link in the "General
4. information" block.
5. In the dialog, select the "Classpath" tab.
6. Click the "Add external jar" button.
7. Select the file "/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar"
8. Close the dialog.
9. Start tomcat 7 from Eclipse.

as described here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1392392/3871208)

Cheers

Comment: What question are you answering? As you can read the problem is that the *Tomcat 7* is out of sync in Eclipse... This has nothing to do with classpath problem on Tomcat 6!!

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue and solved by doing following changes

1. First Close Eclipse
2. Copy all files from TOMCAT_7_HOME/conf
3. Paste inside to  WORKSPACE_FOLDER/Servers/Tomcatv7.0Server-atlocalhostconfig
4. Start Eclipse
5. Open the Servers project, click on the Tomcat 7 project and refresh
6. Start Tomcat from Eclipse

[final view of Ecclipse after fix server issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thRg2.png)