# Why is my Tomcat-deployed web.xml not being read by the host server?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a fully-functional web application hosted in a server. It works perfectly using localhost but when I start Tomcat 7.0.59 on the server and try to reach the application from my local machine, it loads the html and css, and then breaks when trying to hit the first Controller Servlet:

```
function loadRows(fullAccess)
{
     var review_ID = location.search.split('review=')[1];

     $.ajax({
            url : "LoginController",
            type : "post",
            data : {
                "reviewID" : review_ID 
            },
            ...
```

So I am pretty sure that it is not reading web.xml correctly, which is where my Servlets/Servlet-Mappings are defined.

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

  <display-name>MVCDemo</display-name>
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>mvcdemo.controllers.LoginController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/LoginController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>UpdateController</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>mvcdemo.controllers.UpdateController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>UpdateController</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/UpdateController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>SubmitController</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>mvcdemo.controllers.SubmitController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>SubmitController</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/SubmitController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I even tried adding

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>foo.jsp</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>
```

To see whether the app would break when trying to find foo.jsp and not finding it (the actual file is called index.jsp), but index.jsp is still being rendered so web.xml is clearly not being loaded. Any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: Restart the browser and try again with foo.jsp. You should get an error.

Comment: Any error in `catalina.out`?

Comment: catalina.out has:
"`Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap`
"

Comment: The error in `catalina.out` indicates a problem with your Tomcat installation or deployment. Are you running any other webapp on this Tomcat instance? Do you get the default "It works !" page when you access the base host URL?

Comment: When in my browser I go to http://IPaddress:8080 it lands on Tomcat's homepage (server status, manager app, host manager, etc). I'm not running any other app on Tomcat.

Comment: I would think Tomcat was working fine if it lands on the homepage right?

Comment: Probably, but not necessarily. How did you install Tomcat? The problem could also be with your webapp deployement. How did you package it? Also please include the relevant parts of `catalina.out` in your question so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @DavidLevesque I downloaded itfrom mymachine and moved the folder over (server has not Internet access so I can't download it there). I already updated theEnvironment Variables. I have tried packaging it as a WAR (using Eclipse) and deploying it withTomcar Manager, or also having the project directory sitting on the server and pointing at it from my machine's browser (ipaddress:8080/path/to/file/index.jsp) Both ways fail to load web.xml. Those are the only lines in my catalina.out. But that file is a day old even though I have rebooted Tomcat about30 times.How can I produce catalina.out again?

Comment: You should see new entries in `catalina.out` on each restart. If you don't see anything new, it could be that the user running the Tomcat process does not have write permission on the log folder. Make sure that the filysystem permissions in Windows allows Tomcat to write there.

Comment: what version of java is running on the server?
also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392383/server-tomcat-v6-0-server-at-localhost-failed-to-start)

Comment: What operating system are you using on machine where you have instaled tomcat and deployed your app?

Answer (score 1):

> Web.XML
>
> The web.xml file is derived from the Servlet specification, and
>   contains information used to deploy and configure the components of
>   your web applications. When configuring Tomcat for the first time,
>   this is where you can define servlet mappings for central components
>   such as JSP. Within Tomcat, this file functions in the same way as
>   described in the Servlet specification. **The only divergence in
>   Tomcat's handling of this file is that a user has the option of
>   utilizing TOMCAT-HOME/conf/web.xml to define default values for all
>   contexts. If this method is utilized, Tomcat will use
>   TOMCAT-HOME/conf/web.xml as a base configuration, which can be
>   overwritten by application-specific WEB-INF/web.xml files.**

source: https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-configuration

I tink in your case Tomcat does not overwrite the WEB-INF/web.xml and is looking in conf folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the project and have an eye while copying all files to new project.

Basically you need to overwrite web.xml deployment descriptor.